# pyspark column type casting in pivot

Tags: pyspark, pivot

I have a dataframe where I want to create pivot table from 2 columns, i'm using the question header column which will have its value pivoted like below : age , age_numeric
and the answer header is the value , my problem is I want to put the value of the answer header in a list which I'm doing using collect_list function, but the problem is i want the new column like age_numeric to be list of int, while column age to be list of strings, based on question type column, but when i try the code it always gives me a list of strings, any idea how to solve this problem?

this is the code

```
y=output.groupby("sessionId").pivot("questionHeader").
agg(collect_list(when(col("questionType")=="numericAnswer",
col("answerHeader")
.cast("float")).when(col("questionType")!="numericAnswer",col("answerHeader"))))
```

this is what i get

| session id |        Age        | Age_numeric

|     1      | ["20-25 years"]   | ["20"]

|     3      | ["20-25 years"]   | ["20"]

This is what i want

| session id |        Age        | Age_numeric

|     1      | ["20-25 years"]   | [20]

|     3      | ["20-25 years"]   | [20]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output as in the last two rows, then you do not require a pivot, just groupby and collect_list on each of the two columns To get the list of integers for Age_numeric, apply .cast("array< int>"), or change the type of Age_numeric column before collect_list().

##### Replicate  the data

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
data = [(1, "20-25 years", "20"), (3, "20-25 years", "20")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["session_id", "Age", "Age_numeric"])
```

##### Replicate the output

```
df_out = (df.groupBy("session_id")
            .agg(F.collect_list("Age").alias("Age"), 
                 F.collect_list("Age_numeric")
                         .cast("array<int>") 
                         .alias("Age_numeric"))
```

Comment: That sounds like a great idea ! only thing is i used pivot because I want the column names to be dynamic as I can't define the schema of the dataframe because i dont know the column names, so is there a way to do it dynamically ?